# Artificial intelligence - Search algorithm from coordinates

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Assume that we have have this grid with coordinates.
[image]

We start at 0.0 (it's actully 0,0 but my Libre Office cannot handle 0,0 due to my settings) and we want to go to -3.10

Is there any search algorithm for this type of problem?
Start position and stop position can change too.

This is a math question and I'm pretty sure that this is well used in game development, but I have not found any algorithm that can handle these kind of problems.

Comment: Adjacency of cells in your pictorial representation might correspond to the existence of an edge between two vertices in a network (or 'graph'). Then I guess you are looking for the shortest path between two vertices?

Comment: @Ali yes. Shortest path is from start to stop is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you looked through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem?

Comment: @Ali Thanks! But what is most used? There is lot's of algorithm out there. Most of them works only in theory.

Comment: @Ali Can I use Simplex method for this?

Comment: I don’t know your *simplex method* but a cheap to implement algorithm is the *$A^{*}$-algorithm, which is commonly used in games (indie games at least). You may also look up *Dijkstra‘s* algorithm.

Comment: @PrudiiArca Thanks! What do you prefer? A* or Dijkstra?

Comment: @PrudiiArca Found C code for Dijkstra  https://www.codewithc.com/dijkstras-algorithm-in-c/

Comment: I have learnt about Dijkstra about five years ago, so I don’t know about its performance. Since A-star is commonly tought in game programming tutorials I guess it is faster or easier to implement (or both)

Comment: @PrudiiArca Ok! I will take A* then. Thanks for the information.